# How to change the background color of navigation drawer android?

Tags: android

I want to make my navigation drawer for dark mode but I can't find where I have to change the code. This pic will help you understand my question

[image]

how to change the color to black and also how to change the text color to white?

Comment: What kind of app is this? What technology was used?

Comment: java and xml (android app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is a layout for the navigation activity and in the XML file we can edit it.

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/motivationQuoteColor"  HERE IS THE CHANGE I NEED TO DO
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_front_navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_front_navigation_drawer">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

summary, go to that activity where we slide left to right then the drawer opens, then open the layout file, and then you have to go to the code above and then change the code there.